# Get current folder path of http trigger function in Azure in dotnet core

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-functions, google-shopping-api, google-content-api

I am creating a http trigger function in dotnet core  where I need to find current folder path of my project shopping-samples.Though i am able to execute below code in local in vs code.
private static readonly string defaultPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal),
"shopping-samples");
How i can get the folder path in Azure for this http trigger function.
The path in local is showing :C:\Users\shash\Documents\shopping-samples  and it is working perfectly fine in local.
Please help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Azure functions reading custom files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58731103/azure-functions-reading-custom-files)

Comment: No it is not working even in local.
It is fetching path= "C:\\Users\\shash\\Documents\\shopping-samples\\bin\\Debug\\netcoreapp3.1\\GoogleAuth\\shopping-samples"
actual path should be=C:\Users\shash\Documents\shopping-samples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code to get current folder path:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace FunctionApp8
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log,
            ExecutionContext context)
        {
            return new OkObjectResult(context.FunctionAppDirectory);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks it worked